# How to place a child div behind the parent div?

Tags: html, css

My question is exactly like the subject says, I have tried below, but it doesn't work.

My HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
#parent {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
#children {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the parent element's `z-index`, and then give the child a negative `z-index` value.

In doing so, you are essentially removing the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) that was previously established between the elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpvhoLyj/)

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
#children {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: why does this not work when parent's position is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the z-index altogether and add overflow:hidden to the parent, then move the child out of the way by modifying the top or margin-top property to be -100px.

```css
#parent {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    overflow:auto;
}
#children {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="children">child</div>
</div>
```